# yii2 - how to set currency decimal value

Tags: php, yii2, money-format

I want my currency to ignore decimal value, so far I have this:

main.php:

```
'formatter' => [
   'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
   'thousandSeparator' => '.',
   'decimalSeparator' => ',',
   'currencyCode' => '€',

],
```

view:

```
[
   'attribute' => 'Score',
   'format' => 'currency',
],
```

Any idea on how to move forward?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$currencyCode-detail) on `currencyCode`:

> The 3-letter ISO 4217 currency code indicating the default currency to use

Try setting `currencyCode` to `'EUR'` (though that doesn't seem to be that important) and put the formatter in an array

```
[
   'attribute' => 'Score',
   'format' => [
       'currency',
       'EUR',
       [
           \NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
           \NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
       ]
    ],
],
```

This requires the PHP intl extension to be installed.  Status of the extension can be tested by calling `extension_loaded('intl')`.  In absence of the extension, your best bet is probably to write a custom formatter.

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

class Formatter extends \yii\i18n\Formatter
{
    public function asRoundedCurrency($value, $currency)
    {
        return $this->asInteger(round($value)) . ' ' . $currency;
    }
}
```

Use it instead of the default formatter an then call it like this:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Score',
    'format' => ['roundedCurrency', 'EUR'],
]
```

This also allows you to freely set the currency symbol.

Comment: i am getting this error `Class 'NumberFormatter' not found` and i have imported `yii\i18n\Formatter`

Comment: @rob180 NumberFormatter is a standard [PHP object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php), I forgot to add some backslashes. Should be fixed now.  Please note that one needs to have the PHP intl extensions installed for this to work.

Comment: @rob180 You can test if it's available by calling `extension_loaded('intl')`.  This should evaluate to `true` if the extensions is present.  Unfortunately, the next best alternative seems to be to implement a custom formatter inheriting from `yii\i18n\Formatter`.  I'll see if I can put together a minimal class.

Comment: @tarleb would you please explain more on writing a custom formatter? I'm not sure where to place the files, what name they should have, etc. I am getting the error 'Unknown format type: roundedCurrency'.

Comment: OK I got it. It was necessary to specify the custom class in the formatter component configuration: 'class' => 'app\components\Formatter'

Answer (score 3):

In main.php:

```
'formatter' => [
   'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
   'locale' => 'yourLocale', //ej. 'es-ES'
   'thousandSeparator' => '.',
   'decimalSeparator' => ',',
   'currencyCode' => 'EUR',

],
```

Be sure that php_intl extensions is installed. It works for me.

Link to the documentation [yii-i18n-formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html).