# Yii2 Currency Formatter set 4 fractions after decimal

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to set 4 digit fractions after decimal,

```
for example : Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($model->amount) 

current output is : $ 65.58
expected output is : $ 65.5765
```

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742656/yii2-how-to-set-currency-decimal-value), but i m getting error as "Class 'NumberFormatter' not found".

How can I use following properties in my main config file, these properties are mentioned in Formatter class

```
  [
      NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
      NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS => 2,
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property takes only effect if the [PHP intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) is installed. Install `intl` and class `NumberFormatter` will be available. The rest is just like in your configuration.

Comment: @ Bizley : Thanks, it works fine after installing the  [PHP intl extension.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). I have one more question, is there any way to get a currency symbol using currency code?

Comment: Add currency code here: `Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($amount, $currencyCode)` $currencyCode must be 3-letter ISO 4217 code and will be displayed according to your `locale` settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help .. !!